# editing one column in the Csv File

Tags: c#, csv

i am trying to editing only one column within my csv. however the code does not seem to affect the file. the changes im trying to make is to change to separate the 4th column data with a comma.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "kaviaReport 02_08_2016.csv");
        var fileContents = ReadFile(filePath);
        foreach (var line in fileContents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static IList<string> ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        var results = new List<string>();
        int lineCounter = 0;
        string currentLine = string.Empty;
        var target = File
 .ReadAllLines(fileName);
        while ((currentLine = fileName) != null)//while there are lines to read
        {
            List<string> fielded = new List<string>(currentLine.Split(','));
            if (lineCounter != 0)
            {
                //If it's not the first line
                var lineElements = currentLine.Split(',');//split your fields into an array
                var replace = target[4].Replace(' ', ',');//replace the space in position 4(field 5) of your array
                results.Add(replace);
                //target.WriteAllLines(string.Join(",", fielded));//write the line in the new file

            }

            lineCounter++;
            File.WriteAllLines(fileName, target);


        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: `while ((currentLine = fileName) != null)` ... care to explain?

Comment: If you don't have any restrictions try library: CSVHelper (https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) This task becomes more-less trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code has some errors.
The biggest one is the assignement of `currentLine` to `fileName`. This, of course is meaningless if you want to loop over the lines. So you need a foreach over the read lines.
Then inside the loop you should use the variable lineElements to get the 5 column available after the splitting of the `currentLine`.
Finally the rewrite of the file goes outside the loop and should use the result list.

```
// Loop, but skip the first line....
foreach(string currentLine in target.Skip(1))
{
    // split your line into an array of strings
    var lineElements = currentLine.Split(',');

    // Replace spaces with commas on the fifth column of lineElements 
    var replace = lineElements[4].Replace(' ', ',');

    // Add the changed line to the result list 
    results.Add(replace);
}

// move  outside the foreach loop the write of your changes 
File.WriteAllLines(fileName, results.ToArray());
```

Something has occured to my mind while writing this code. It is not clear if you want to rewrite the CSV file with only the data in the fifth column expanded with commas or if you want to rewrite the entire line (also column 0,1,2,3,4 etc..) in this latter case you need a different code

```
// Replace spaces with commas on the fifth column of lineElements 
// And resssign the result to the same fifth column
lineElements[4] = lineElements[4].Replace(' ', ',');

// Add the changed line to the result list putting the comma 
// between the array of strings lineElements
results.Add(string.Join(",", lineElements);
```

Comment: thank you very much for your solution this has solve my issue. however when i  check the updated file it only display the 5th column which has been edited. id like to view all the column + the updated column

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about that. If you want to rewrite the whole line you need the second part of the code. If it is unclear I could replace the current one

Comment: thank you very much its all working. much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`while ((currentLine = fileName) != null)` will set currentLine = fileName which will make the line always true and make a infinite loop

I would write it as a for loop instead of a while

```
public static IList<string> ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        var target = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList();
        // i = 1 (skip first line)
        for (int i = 1; i < target.Count; i++)
        {
           target[4] = target[4].Replace(' ', ','); //replace the space in position 4(field 5)
        }
        File.WriteAllLines(fileName, target);
        // Uncomment the RemoveAt(0) to remove first line
        // target.RemoveAt(0);
        return target;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the it seems to be doing what i am wanting to do. however its only affecting row 5 in every column not just the full 5th column